# Retrieve post data via WPDB class

Tags: custom-post-types, images, query, post-meta, wpdb

I'm trying to figure out doing a custom query using the $wpdb Object.

I have custom type posts, event_posts, that have meta data, images, as well as event dates which are input in the post with the FT Calendar plugin.

I can get posts that have event dates (dates pulled from the ftcalendar_events table), but my first issue is that when I query the post type it comes back as "revision" and not "event_posts".

My second issue is that I don't know how to retrieve the metadata and images for the post.

Here's what I am using below.

Why am I doing it this way you might ask?  Because I need to order the posts based on the event date, which is pulled from the ftcalendar_events table, and even though the standard wp query methods retrieve the post with all of that information, there isn't a way to order them by the event date.

Any ideas how to retrieve all of that?

```
global $wpdb;
$poos = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT
    p.post_title AS title,
    p.post_type AS type,
    p.post_content AS content,
    ev.start_datetime AS start
    FROM
    " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts AS p,
    " . $wpdb->prefix . "ftcalendar_events AS ev
    WHERE
    p.post_parent = ev.post_parent
    AND
    p.post_type='event_posts'
    ORDER BY
    ev.start_datetime
    ASC
");

//print_r($poos);
//echo '<br><br><br>';

foreach($poos as $poo){
    echo $poo->type.'<br>';
    echo $poo->title.'<br>';
    echo $poo->content.'<br>';
    echo $poo->start.'<br><br><br>';    
}
```

That outputs:

```
revision (should be "event_posts")
Home Town Celebration
Historic 'Home Town' Celebration in Ridgefield WA. An '0ld town' holiday celebration artisans fair and market. December 2013
2013-12-07 11:00:00
```

Comment: For your first issue -- add `AND p.post_type='event_posts'` to your `WHERE` clause. Also: I'm fairly certain there's a much easier way to do what you're trying to do -- have a look at [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) and/or [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: Woops, forgot to add that for this, just added that back in.  Still I don't know how that is possible with WP_Query to order by even date when it's from another table.  Do you?

Comment: No, I think you're probably right.  If you need to get data from a non-standard WP table, you need to use `$wpdb`.